# why jquery form not submitting on first click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have one popup modal which submit to an ajax page after validation. Validation and submission are working perfectly. But the only issue, on first click it is not submitting the form or validation.On the second click it is working perfect.

Code:

```
<script>
      $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $('#gen-bar-form').validate({
                ignore: [],
                rules: { 
                        firstName: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        editor: {

                            required: true
                        }
                },

          submitHandler: function(form) {

             $("#loader-bg").css("visibility", "visible");

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'action/file.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
            var GenTokRet = JSON.parse(data);
            $("#gen-msg").html("<p>"+GenTokRet+"<p>");
            $("#loader-bg").css("visibility", "hidden");  

            }
          });

          }

          }); 

        });

      });
    </script>
```

Comment: do some console.log() in your js code see in whitch line it stops working if everything works check your network tab in developer tools see if the package is sent or not

Comment: when i did console.log() before  $('#gen-bar-form').validate, it is working. after the validate function also console.log() is working. On first click the package is not sent. But on the second click, the package is sending.

Comment: did you try putting console.log() in the callback of the validate function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did wrong, because, you are using prevent default function for stopping the form ,
though jQuery validate will auto stop submitting form till it is valid.
so just type validate function on submit function not needed

Comment: sorry,. i Didnt get you

Comment: Got it. I removed  $('form').on('submit', function (e) { } . Thank you verymuch